# How to set Android certificate to Expo?

Tags: expo, google-play-console

I built an android application using `expo build:android` and when I upload the app to Google Play Console it returns an error saying that the certificate is wrong.

I go to `App Integrity` in Google Play Console and I can see the keys (App signing key certificate):

```
MD5 certificate fingerprint: XXXXXX
SHA-1 certificate fingerprint: XXXXX
SHA-256 certificate fingerprint: XXXX
```

I run the `expo fetch:android:hashes` and the values are different. How can I update the keys on `Expo` or Google Play Console for the keys to match?

Thanks